# How to write Like Condition within In Clause for thousands of Items

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to filter Items of table PartMaster based on the input from table PARTINPUT using LIKE condition. Both the table has multiple entries.

Table 1: PartMaster

```
PartNo
======
Part1.DRW
Part2.DRW
Part3.ASM
Part3.PRT
Part1.XLT
Part2.ASM
Part3.ASM
Part3.DRW
Part4.ASM
Part4.DRW


Part5000.PRT
```

Table2: PartINPUT

```
PART
=====
Part1
Part2
Part3
    .
.
.
PART5000
```

I am trying to find a items from table PartMaster where

```
select *
from PartMaster PM 
where PM.PartNo in (select PI.PART from PARTINPUT PI 
                    where PM.PartNo like '%PI.PART%')
```

I have tried:

```
select *
from PartMaster PM
where PM.PartNo in (select PI.PART from PARTINPUT PI where PM.PartNo like '%PI.PART%)'
```

and

```
select *
from PartMaster PM
where PM.PartNo in (select PI.PART from PARTINPUT PI where PM.PartNo like '%' || PI.PART ||'%')'
```

Results should return all the items from table PartMaster based on matching %part% from second input table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right you want to join on the `partno` of `partmaster` beginning with a `part` of `partinput` and a dot. (Or maybe without the dot, remove it from the query in that case).

```
SELECT *
       FROM partmaster pm
            INNER JOIN partinput pi
                       ON pm.partno LIKE pi.part || '.%';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abbf51b4301d40b213e06b989055d248)

Comment: The results should skip Part4.DRW and Part4.PRT from the list as Part4 is not present in the table which I am specifying in the criteria(like condition). Above join returns all the parts. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @user3442687: Works for me. See the fiddle (in the edit).